# Xcode 10.2.1: A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, xcode10, xcode10.2

When provisioning a React Native application for Release (Debug works) in Xcode I run into a familiar error here on Stackoverflow when trying to run it on a device for testing:

> A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found

But the solutions proposed in other questions don't work (I tried all of them):

- Setting "Legacy Build System" for the Workspace, Project, etc.
- Deploy on different iOS device
- Cleaning build folder
- Removing all provisioning profiles stored locally and re-adding them
- Restarting Xcode
- Also tried different changes to Build Settings from other answers

Environment:

- Xcode Version 10.2.1 (10E1001) <== Updated just recently, this could be the cause

The provisioning profile:

- Type iOS Distribution
- Status Active
- Expires 2020/06/16 Enabled
- Capabilities Game Center, In-App Purchase
- Matches exactly the app's App ID

[image: Signing Settings]
[image: Project Settings]

Comment: Maybe your app identifier is registered with another developer account?

Comment: @Geru It's under the same account

Comment: Is the device to which you are installing the app listed in the available devices for that exact Distribution Profile?

Comment: @Aaron seems like I was using a provisioning profile for AppStore distribution where I should be using Ad-Hoc profile for distributing the Release version on test devices. Using Ad-Hoc profile seems to have solved the issue.

Comment: Awesome. I converted to an answer for visibility.